# How to do loop that includes function and data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, iteration

I want to make the loop function like below. The result I want is that

```
set.seed(1)
test = data.frame("0" = c(14,22,14,13), "1" = c(12,5,4,12), "2" = c(14,5,12,10),  "3" = c(13,14,7,3))
colnames(test) = c("0", "1", "2", "3")
test["-1"] = 0

solution = data.frame(A = c(0, 1,2,3, 3), B = c(2,1,3,2, 1), C = c(1,3,2,0, NA), D = c(3,1,2,3, NA))
colnames(solution) = c("0", "1", "2", "3")

chosen_spots = colnames(solution)
for (m in chosen_spots) {
  type = solution[,m]
  type[is.na(type)] = -1
  type = as.character(type) 

  data = matrix(0, 1, length(chosen_spots))
  for (x in 1:length(chosen_spots)) {
    model = function(m){
      lm(test[,m] ~ test[,type[1]] + test[,type[2]] + test[,type[3]]+ test[,type[4]], data = test)
    } 
    model(m)
    data[1, x] = model(m)$coefficients[1]
   }
   result = colMeans(data)
   print(paste("The intercept mean is",result))
}
print(paste("The intercept mean is",result))
data
```

The result looks like this

```
[1] "The intercept mean is 1.77635683940025e-15"
[1] "The intercept mean is -4.15452614407147e-16"
[1] "The intercept mean is 0"
[1] "The intercept mean is 0"
[1] "The intercept mean is 0"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
```

It seems that my looping does not work for data = matrix(0, 1, length(chosen_spots)). It seems only record the last iteration. Could you please help with what is wrong? What I want that the "data" will be something like

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0.1    0.4    0.32    0
```

Where the entries are all the results of the iterations not only the last iteration so that in the end, I want to take the colMeans(data). Thank you.

Comment: What's `test["-1"] = 0` supposed to do?

Comment: @Harshvardhan When the entry is NA I change that entry to -1 and the column name -1 has entries all 0. So I just add a column (named "-1" with all entries are 0). When I use NA as a column name, I found an error to call that column so I change it to -1 instead. But it is not the issue at the moment

Comment: You need to talk more about your goal. The third iteration is your first problem. In that iteration `m` is `"2"` and `type` is `"1"  "3"  "2"  "0"  "-1"`. You then run your model regressing `test[, "m"]` on some variables, one of which is `test[,type[3]]`, so you are regressing `test[, "2"]` using `test[, "2"]` as a predictor. In this case, the intercept is indeed 0---all coefficients are 0 except for the `test[, "2"]` coefficient which is 1 because `test[, "2"] = test[, "2"]`. It sounds like that's not what you want to do, but I don't know what you want to do any more than R does.

Comment: I would say there's a red flag in your inner loop: `for (x in 1:length(chosen_spots))`. The only time you use `x` inside the loop is to assign the result do `data[1, x]`. With no `x` in the `model` definition, the result will be the same every time. It's not "only recording the last iteration", rather you aren't changing anything in iterations - every iteration runs the same exact code. But I don't know what you want to change...

Comment: @GregorThomas yes, I want to do iteration, for example when m = 2 (taken from type = c(1,3,2,0,-1)) I want the result for model m is stored to the matrix called "data" and so on until all values for m are evaluated.  I use x in hoping that when x = 1 for m =1, x = 2 for m = 3, x = 3 for m = 0, x = 4 for m = -1. So the dimension of the matrix result wil l be 1 x length(colnames(chosen_spots)). And the final goal is to take the mean of these values of this data matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by editing like this

```
set.seed(1)
test = data.frame("0" = c(14,22,14,13), "1" = c(12,5,4,12), "2" = c(14,5,12,10), "3" = c(13,14,7,3))
colnames(test) = c("0", "1", "2", "3")
test["-1"] = 0

solution = data.frame(A = c(0, 1,2,3, 3), B = c(2,1,3,2, 1), C = c(1,3,2,0, NA), D = c(3,1,2,3, NA))
colnames(solution) = c("0", "1", "2", "3")

spots = colnames(solution)
data = matrix(0, 1, length(spots))
for (i in 1:length(spots)){
  chosen_spots = spots[I]
  type = solution[,chosen_spots]
  type[is.na(type)] = -1
  type = as.character(type)
  model = function(chosen_spots){
  lm(test[,chosen_spots] ~ test[,type[1]] + test[,type[2]] + test[,type[3]]+ test[,type[4]], data = test)
  }
model(chosen_spots)
data[1, i] = model(chosen_spots)$coefficients[1]
}
result = rowMeans(data)
print(paste("The intercept mean is",result))
```